# Messaging menu in 13.04 missing

Tags: 13.04, messaging-menu

I've just updated to 13.04 this weekend. It was a clean install. Since then I cannot find the Messaging Menu working properly as before. It doesn't integrate with online accounts and shows only the Empathy statuses. I've reinstalled and even downloaded a new ISO file for another install, and everything remains the same.

Anyone facing the same problem? Ideas on how to solve it? I'm using a Dell Vostro 3500, 64-bit (dual-boot Win 7).

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out just now.

The Messaging Menu actually changes its appearance when an application becomes active. For example, if Facebook is kept active for a while and someone interacts with you (by liking your post, comment or messaging you) the Menu envelope will become blue.

Comment: Add Gmail to thunderbird?